# How do I colour a fluid simulation in Cycles based on velocity?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, fluid-simulation

I want to assign a gradient to the water simulations I have. I want to do this by the velocity in the current voxel, so the fastest moving areas will be red and the slowest blue.

How would this be accomplished using blender cycles nodes?

Comment: This feature is not possible using the current fluid-simulation, download a mantaflow-build. You have more chance to access the particle velocity there...

Comment: What kind of simulation do you have: Particle, external import, or Blender Fluid sim?

Comment: @ScottMilner Blenders fluid sim, I was think the attribute node could be used in a way to get the fluids velocity and colour that against a gradient but I cannot see a way of doing it

Comment: I've edited my answer to simplify the setup for particle velocity and particle speed. See the second answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Blender 2.82 and later, the fluid simulation engine used in previous versions has been replaced with Mantaflow. When Mantaflow simulates the fluid it provides a particle system that can be used to determine the velocity of the fluid in that region of the simulation.

To achieve this, use a Point Density node set to the Liquid Domain object with the Liquid particle system with a material similar to the following :

[image: material nodes]

This takes the Object coordinates and converts into World coordinates - this is required as the particle system is always defined with respect to world coordinates. The Point Density defined the Object (the domain) and the particle system (Liquid) using World Space. Set the Radius to a suitable value such that the influence of each particle is large enough to prevent gaps and select Particle Velocity for the Color Space. The Color output will now represent the velocity of that section of fluid (with RGB representing X,Y,Z velocities.

In my example I used Separate, Absolute, Combine nodes to avoid negative values for use to colour the mesh for demonstration purposes. You can use a Vector Math 'Distance' node to convert the Color directly into a 'speed' instead, if desired.

Note that the Point Density can only be used with Cycles (ie, not Eevee).

Answer (score 5):

The [answer by @RichSedman](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194945/31447) is perfect but you can get the same result with a much easier setup:

First of all, you don't need a *Texture Coordinate* node and no *Vector Transform* node unless you want to modify the texture coordinates. And you can get rid of all those *Separate*, *Absolute* and *Combine* nodes as well.

The only thing you need is the *Point Density* node where you choose your domain as *Object* and *Liquid* as the *Particle System* and *Space* > *World Space*. For the *Interpolation* you can choose whatever you like, while *Linear* and *Cubic* result in smooher color transitions than *Closest*. Then choose *Color Source* > *Particle Velocity*. Plug the *Color* output into a *Vector Math* node set to *Absolute* to avoid negative values. The result you can either use as color for Principled, Diffuse, Emission etc.

If you just want to colorize the speed of the particles set the *Color Source*  to *Particle Speed* instead of *Particle Velocity*. You'll then get greyscale values where the speed is mapped from 0 to 1 which you can plug directly into a *Color Ramp* and give them the colors you want, with a color for the slowest speed on the left and the highest speed on the right. Add as many colors inbetween as you like.

If your fluid particles are too slow for your taste, so that the color from most of the mesh stays on the right side, you might consider to increase the speed values with a *Math* node set to either *Multiply* or *Add* between the *Point Density* and *Color Ramp* nodes.

1. Particle velocity:
   [image: velocity]
2. Particle speed:
   [image]

Comment: Could you adapt this answer to get the doppler-effect requested in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214351/35559), by taking the  dot-product of the velocity with the normalized vector from the particle's position to a defined viewing-point? I'm tempted, but inexperienced with fluids.

Comment: I have no knowledge of the things illustrated there, but the thing I get out of that is red symbolizes upward movement and blue downward movement. In the first answer the color is separated into XYZ values, I guess there it would be possible to get the Z velocity from -1 (down) to 1 (up). Making those values absolute would get rid of negative values resulting in black, and  some _Greater Than_ math node could switch between red and blue. Or instead of _Absolute_ you could use a _Map Range_ node mapping -1 to 1 values to 0 to 1. Combining these informations could produce desired results.

Comment: The color-coding is 'Towards Probe', and 'Away From Probe', so it would be the dot-product as described.. fully Away  -> -1, fully Towards -> 1, map range ( -1 to 1 ) --> (0 to 1), put through a color-ramp. The vector to the probe is [(fixed) probe position] - [particle position], normalised. The velocity could be normalised, too, so only the direction is coded, not the speed-in-that-direction.

Comment: You have definitely more technical background on what is happening there than me. The _Vector Math_ node has a _Dot Product_ function so it should be no problem to enter to vectors there. But I'm not sure if it functions as expected since the particle velocities are all given in relation to world coordinates. But as I said, I'm lacking the technological background to understand what there is to do.

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I have time, but will probably get tangled up in the weeds of the sim :D

Comment:  Reading the other question again I cannot get the information you are talking about, there is no mentioning of fully towards and fully away or the probe vector and a dot product. There is only red upwards, blue downwards and brighter color means faster. This should really be easy with the Z velocity (or X or Y, depending on which direction should be taken as upwards). So without your explanation I would have never known what the goal there is.

Comment: @Gordon You need a Shader node between your output and the Material Output node - as it stands this won’t render in Cycles as you’ve connected a vector/colour directly to Material Output’s Surface node. Also, the “optional” Multiply node is going to create some strange results if one or more of the channels is negative - since it will convert the vector into a scalar value.

Comment: @RichSedman You need a _Shader_ node or it won't render in Cycles? I've shown the render in my images... If you plug colors, vectors etc. directly into the _Material Output_, it works like using a _Viewer_ node: basically an _Emission Shader_ Strength = 1. And for the negative values: in the first setup I used an _Absolute_ node to avoid them - but actually that's not even necessary. The _Point Density_ node has only 2 outputs, _Color_ and _Density_. None of them are negative. _Particle Age/Speed_ are mapped to 0-1, _Particle Velocity_ is XYZ velocity mapped to RGB (from Blender manual).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann it's certainly the case at earlier versions that this wasn't permitted as the colour couldn't be automatically converted to a BSDF. I've not got access to suitable versions to test this so don't know at what version this is apparently no longer the case. For the negatives, for 'Speed' you aren't going to get negatives,true, but for Velocity you will. Also, conversion won't be correct for 'speed' anyway.... consider a particle going at 0.5 in each of the x,y,z directions. Using a straight maths node will give a speed of 0.5 whereas it should actually be 0.866 (by pythagoras).

Comment: Maths node effectively averages all channels `(0.5+0.5+0.5)/3 = 0.5` whereas actual speed would be `sqrt(0.5**2 + 0.5**2 + 0.5**2) = 0.866`

Comment: On using a BSDF: I've clearly stated in my answer the solution works with 2.82 and above because the _Point Density_ node uses Mantaflow's fluid particle system for the particle info. So 1. it works and 2. he might as well use it for diffuse, glass, emission... I just wanted to show the resulting color. Again on negatives and resulting values: for negatives, I've put an _Absolute_ node. For calculating the values: the original question asks for a gradient relative to the velocity, the fastest red and the slowest blue. No need for exact values since they should somehow be normalized anyway.

Comment: Ha - yeah - no worries. I was so in the habit of always connecting shader I didn't realise that had changed - and still did it by habit. Going back through the versions I actually had to go all the way back to 2.79b before Cycles would fail to render as a colour. Back then, connecting anything but a Shader node to Material Output would result in the shader working in 'material' mode but black when rendered. It was a common error back in the day. Looks like 2.80 and Eevee revamped all that and made it more tolerant. It's really strange going back to 2.7. It's changed a lot since then.

Comment: BTW, I wasn't criticising your answer - just trying to help.

Comment: @RichSedman Don't worry, it's all fine - as I said in my answer, yours is perfect. Mine is more like "if you want to have an easy way and don't care for perfection" 