# Simulating Color Doppler with Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I am preparing a presentation for radiology residents. I'd like to use Blender to explain some caractheristics of color Doppler ultrasound (US). Basically, Doppler US allows you to see the blood flow's velocity and direction in the vessels. If the blood flow is towards the US probe, it is colored red. If it is away from the probe it is blue. The brightness of the color determines its velocity, where brighter reds and blues mean higher velocities, and darker tones mean lower velocities. Here's an example to illustrate what I mean:

[image: color Doppler US]

In the picture, the probe is situated at the skin level, which is the top of the image. The red vessels contain flow that goes upwards, and the blue vessels are blue because the flow is downwards. Also, you can observe some yellowish/orange segments in the middle of the red vessles or white parts in the middle of the blue vessels, because the velocities are higher in these sections, so they have a differen shade.

I've tought about creating a tubular hollow structure to represent the vessel and then use fluid simulation inside. I haven't been able to find a way to change the particles' color depending on their velocity and direction. Is there a way to achieve this or do I need a more professional fluid simulator?